# Which partition do devices read, if there are multiple? Is there a standard?

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive

Say I have a 128GB USB drive and I want to use it for multiple things. I want to install Ventoy on it, so I can drag'n'drop ISO files to it, and make it easy to install any operating system. On top of that, I also want a small FAT32 partition for stuff like firmware updates on devices that require a FAT32 partition.

Ventoy automatically creates two partitions: 32MB FAT32 EFI partition and `total_usb_size - 32MB` large exFAT partition (the remaining).

[image]

According to their documentation, Ventoy can read all partitions on the drive, so I should be able to shrink that exFAT partition and create a new FAT32 partition. However, my biggest concern is this: Which partition do devices read from first? Is there a standard?

I have a bunch of devices that I can update firmware on, such as my lawnmower, 3D printer, and PC motherboard. They require a FAT32 partition. However, none of them states what happens, if I have more than 1 partition. If I do my partitioning like this:

[image]

Is there a chance that every device simply reads the first partition and ignores the rest? Or can each device implement "partition reading" differently? Is there a better way to create a "one USB drive to rule them all"?

Comment: I suggest you simply try/experiment! If you have doubts, you could always get another cheap USB drive. Separation of concerns is also a thing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard for this, as there's no real standard for appliance firmware upgrades in general.

However, partitions are always stored in some specific order, which typically corresponds to the disk order (e.g. your "FAT32, 16GB" partition would be stored in the first slot) and partitioning tools try to maintain that order. The Linux `fdisk` tool can be used to sort entries if needed.

So it would be reasonable to assume that devices will look at the *first slot* in the MBR partition table (especially when that's the only slot that most "normal" USB sticks will be using anyway).

As an exception, if you're updating your PC motherboard in the regular way (using the current firmware's update app, with a working display) it will likely detect *all* partitions and offer to select from them, as the updater is often just a regular UEFI application that relies on file access functions provided by the UEFI kernel. (which at this point will have already scanned all disks for anything bootable – this *is* covered by the UEFI specification).

Comment: _"partitioning tools try to maintain that order"_ - most tools I've used will use the free unused slot, so partitions will generally be in order of creation, which can be different than order on disk. A notable exception is Windows's `diskmgmt.msc` which will reindex partitions on some (all?) operations.

Comment: Also: make sure to use a primary partition, not an extended partition, for best compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If by "devices read" you mean "computers boot", the question doesn't
apply for EFI boot.

The EFI partition is identified by a standard partition-id that is
stored in the partition-table of the disk.

The EFI BIOS will scan the disk, searching for that partition-id.
Once found, it will initiate the boot process from this partition.
That partition can be anywhere on the disk, as in your layout
the EFI boot partition is located at the *end* of the disk.

So you may add as many partitions as you like - the boot will always
start with the EFI partition.

You may store boot-loaders in the EFI partition that will continue
the boot from any other partition they are programmed to use.

---

For non-computer devices, there are no rules.
It all depends on how the firmware was programmed.

I have encountered :

- Device that refused to accept a disk that wasn't exactly
  in its format, partition-table and file-system
- Device that read only the first partition
- Device that only understood FAT32
- Etc Etc

I don't think that it's possible to come up with one USB disk
that fits all. You could have for example multiple partitions,
formatted with different formats, but you may be required for some
device to move its partition so as to place it as the first.

It all depends on the devices that you wish to support and their
characteristics.

Comment: I think "devices" is defined in the following paragraph: _"I have a bunch of devices that I can update firmware on, such as my lawnmower, 3D printer, and PC motherboard"_

Comment: @gronostaj: The tool he uses, Ventoy, created an EFI boot disk. Most printers etc don't do EFI boot. It's possible that he needs another tool than Ventoy.

Comment: Yes, he knows that. The "devices" (lawnmower etc.) look for firmware _somewhere_ on regular, non-bootable, storage-only USB drives. The question is what will these devices do with multi-partition drives and how to make it simultaneously Ventoy-compatible and firmware-upgrade-compatible. It's not about EFI-bootability, that part is solved with Ventoy.

Comment: @gronostaj Exactly. Thank you